# Error in Switching views due to AppDelegate method

Tags: ipad, ios5, uiview

This is what i am doing in my application:

in my appDelegate.m file ,

```
//Four Views
@synthesize fvc;
@synthesize svc;
@synthesize tvc;
@synthesize pvc;

 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
 NSString *name1,*name2,*name3;
 name1 = NSLocalizedString(@"home", nil);
 name2 = NSLocalizedString(@"quote", nil);
name3 = NSLocalizedString(@"ship", nil);
UITabBarController *tabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil]; 

 //[application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
tvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"thirdview"];
fvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"firstview"];
svc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];

 pvc =[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PayViewController"];

fvc.tabBarItem.title = name1;
 fvc.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"];
 fvc.tabBarItem.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(2.0, 0);

 tvc.tabBarItem.title = name2;
 tvc.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ping.png"];
 tvc.tabBarItem.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(0, 2.0);

 svc.tabBarItem.title = name3;
 svc.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"zoom.png"];    
 svc.tabBarItem.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(-5.0, 0);

 NSLog(@"appdelegate %@ and %@",svc,svc.title);

 tabBar.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:fvc,svc,tvc,nil];

 // the below line does not allow [self.navigationController pushViewController:svNew  animated:YES]; to function

 self.window.rootViewController = tabBar;
 // Override point for customization after application launch.
 return YES;
```

In my fvc view im performing change view operation in okPressed method:

```
 - (IBAction)okPressed:(id)sender {
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil]; 

 SecondViewController *svNew = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];

 [self.navigationController pushViewController:svNew animated:YES];
 }
```

When i comment the code in the appdelegate method the switching between the views thru the okPressed method is executed successfully. But when I uncomment the appDelegate method it does not perform switching. What i found out was , the code in appdelegate method "self.window.rootViewController = tabBar;" is the culprit. Can anyone guide me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should embed your UITabBarController in a Navigation Controller to make it work:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tabBar];
```

and then

```
self.window.rootViewController = navController;
```

Otherwise you can't push anything since you probably got no UINavigationController to push things to!